# Windows Phone Push Notifications on a Device

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8, mpns

I'm trying to create push notifications for my Windows 8 phone app. I'm using the example from Microsoft (code and demo video links below) which works fine through the emulator but when I debug to the device instead the app runs but never connects to the WPF app which sends the notification. The emulator works fine every time however. I'm making sure to do the following;

- VS has to be in Administrator mode for the WPF app
- In the phone app, in the method SubscribeToService() I've changed the address to the
  name of my pc; `string baseUri = "http://MY-PC-NAME:8000/RegistrationService/Register?uri={0}";`
- I'm always running the WPF app before the Phone app
- I have my firewall turned off to allow access to port 8000

Is there something extra I have to do to get the app to work on an actual device?

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Phone-8-JumpStart-ab6c839a

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-08-Push-Notifications

Comment: How is your phone is connected to your PC? What is the general network configuration? Most probably it's a networking issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an ASP.NET webform insead of WPF and didn't have any problems.  See the link below.  I just added functionality between the phone and the webform provided.  When "Subscribing to Service", as you state in your question (i.e., sending the Device URI to the web service, to send the push notification), I just used the address given from ASP.NET when running the webform (i.e., hit run, and use the address in the address bar).  This should work locally on your machine.

Hope this helps, I've pasted the sample project below from the MSDN samples.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Toast-Notification-Sample-fb20ae13

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that TCP  port number 2195 outbound is opened from the server where you are sending the push from.